# SVG xlink:href path to .jpg not working (inside my website project)

Tags: svg, images

Why, when I open my .svg file alone in the browser it **does** show the picture from **xlink:href** but inside my website project it **does not show** the picture from **xlink:href**?

This is the image from **xlink:href** --> https://s10.postimg.org/ky5y39vvd/Untitled-19.png

Inside my website project I use either img tag or background-image to link to my .svg file...

The point is I want .svg file to work inside my website project :)

This is my SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" baseProfile="full">
    <title>Text Pattern Fill Example</title>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="120" height="140">
            <image xlink:href="https://s10.postimg.org/e2h45vefd/alex-iby.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="300"
             transform="translate(135.780723, 50.780723) rotate(90.000000) translate(-55.780723, -60.780723)"
             /><!-- Image from http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile/6-grass-meadow-tile.php-->
        </pattern>
    </defs>

        <path d="M59.2078786,111.129597 C101.335439,132.142715 115.952158,85.5158857 115.952158,53.9197716 C115.952158,22.3236576 102.07475,5.17108475 70.7357496,5.17108475 C39.3967496,5.17108475 13.4042112,19.8971044 -0.939389391,40.9853457 C-15.28299,62.0735871 17.0803178,90.1164792 59.2078786,111.129597 Z"  transform="translate(55.780723, 60.780723) rotate(-90.000000) translate(-55.780723, -60.780723) " fill="url(#img1)"></path>        
</svg>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
<embed src="image.svg">
```

SVG with **xlink:href** can't show local image inside website.
But **`<embed src="">`** or **`<object data=""></object>`** html tags works well on this situation.

If you want to use **`<img src="" />`** tag you should place external image in your svg file as base64 string format.

Comment: Hi Khainarbyek, welcome to GDSE! I can't really tell if this is an valid answer. Could you [edit] it to include more information as to how this `embed` should work and what you mean by "click action is not working"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`xlink:href` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href). You should instead be using [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href).

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/yj5bgc68/1/)